# How to follow a tag

Tags: support, tags

Today I deceided to follow the `javascript` tag, and I can't figure out how. I see subscribe, and info, but no follow button. Could someone explain how to follow a tag to me?

Comment: Hover over the tag, and then click on the star in the top-left. It toggles from normal over favorite to ignored.

Comment: It's [in the Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics).

Comment: hah just stumbled over this as I also couldn't figure out how to do it, thanks! Maybe that's an indicator of a slight usability flaw in SO...